# Tabs don't work in python anaconda repl on windows

Tags: python, anaconda

```
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 14:34:41) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def func():
... Readline internal error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 768, in hook_wrapper_23
    res = ensure_str(readline_hook(prompt))
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 571, in readline
    self._readline_from_keyboard()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 536, in _readline_from_keyboard
    if self._readline_from_keyboard_poll():
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 556, in _readline_from_keyboard_poll
    result = self.mode.process_keyevent(event.keyinfo)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 243, in process_keyevent
    r = self.process_keyevent_queue[-1](keyinfo)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 286, in _process_keyevent
    r = dispatch_func(keyinfo)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 257, in complete
    completions = self._get_completions()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 200, in _get_completions
    r = self.completer(ensure_unicode(text), i)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\rlcompleter.py", line 80, in complete
    readline.redisplay()
AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'redisplay'
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>
```

This is what I get when I press tab anywhere in the console. Spaces are okay. It's something to do with anaconda as racket's repl is working fine. Updating every package didn't help. Tabs work when I run the program inside a file. The problem exist both in git bash and cmd.

Comment: Did you try updating conda and/or python? Did this issue surface after installing a certain package or since the beginning?

Comment: I tried updating, it didn't do a thing. I don't know how I actually got the issue, it just suddenly appeared and I've since sort of forgotten about it but it kept bugging me...